# UITableView flashes when reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

On my UIViewController I have a UIView and a UITableView. The UIView acts as a loading screen while my XML Parser (RaptureXML) is parsing table data. When its finished it shows the data in the UITableView.

However when I run the app and navigate to a different view controller and then back, the UITableView flashes due to `[self.tableView reloadData];` If I take this out it does not display the data in the table. Can I move this somewhere else?

```
@interface OffersViewController ()

@end

@implementation OffersViewController
@synthesize loadingView;

MoreCobaltOffers *currentFeed;
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.tableView addSubview:loadingView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];

CustomStringParser *customStringParser = [[CustomStringParser alloc] init];

// Download and parse XML data
RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.morecobalt.co.uk/rss/?t=offers"]]];

// Create an reference to AppDelegate
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Create an array to store each feed
appDelegate.offersFeeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Loop Through XML Data
[rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {

    [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

        // Assign element to string
        NSString *title = [repElement child:@"title"].text;
        NSString *subtitle = [repElement child:@"tagline"].text;
        NSString *description = [repElement child:@"description"].text;
        NSString *imageurl = [repElement child:@"image"].text;
        NSString *address = [repElement child:@"address"].text;

        // Assign element value to MoreCobalt.h propertys
        currentFeed = [MoreCobaltOffers alloc];
        currentFeed.title = title;
        currentFeed.imageurl = imageurl;
        currentFeed.addressline = address;

        // DESCRIPTION FORMATTING
        description = [customStringParser parseHTML:description];
        description = [customStringParser parseLinesMultiple:description];
        description = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:description];
        description = [customStringParser appendTermsOfUse:description];
        currentFeed.description = description;

        // SUBTITLE FORMATTING
        subtitle = [customStringParser parseHTML:subtitle];
        subtitle = [customStringParser parseLinesSingle:subtitle];
        subtitle = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:subtitle];
        currentFeed.subtitle = subtitle;

        // Add a new object to the feeds array
        [[appDelegate offersFeeds] addObject:currentFeed];
    }];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
}
```

Comment: When you add the code in a block, this code is executing in another thread, the view are set hidden to quickly, but if you comment `[loadingView setHidden:YES];` the view must be showed.

Comment: Yes thats correct. If you comment [loadingView setHidden:YES]; the view is displayed. How would you suggest we overcome this problem?

Comment: Find the correct way to manage blockCompletion and put this code inside.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I never used RXMLElement, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the view before the TableView. Just change the order in the interface builder.

Here is you view hierarchy:

```
View
  View
     GrayActivity Indicator
     Label  - Loading
  Table View
    TableViewCell
```

Here is how is suppose to be:

```
View
  Table View
    TableViewCell
  View
     GrayActivity Indicator
     Label  - Loading
```

**EDIT**

Please remove this line `[loadingView setHidden:YES]; update your code to the following:

```
[rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {

      [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

         .
         .
         .

      [[appDelegate offersFeeds] addObject:currentFeed];
   }];
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [loadingView setHidden:YES];
      [self.table reloadData];
});
```

}];

Comment: Thanks, did this but didn't fix my issue.

Comment: You still can't see the loading view and the tableView? Can you comment the line [loadingView setHidden:YES]; and tell me if the Loading view is visible ?

Comment: Hi there, If I comment the line the loading view is visible. However uncommented I don't get to see the loading view. I believe its something to do with my block.

Comment: I edit my answer, seems your xml load is asynchronous, so the got hit the line [loadingView setHidden:YES];, before the code in the block is finish.

Comment: Yes the xml load is asynchronous. I added what you said, however now the app is stuck on its launch image :(

Comment: I'm sorry , you should place the code inside the second block.

Comment: Still stuck on the splash screen unfortunately

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap an IF statement around the xml parser and when the condition is false execute [loadingView setHidden:YES]; ?

Comment: I seem to have it working now with the new code above. The loading view shows and then the table displays. However when I navigate to a new view controller and back to this one the table flashes. Im guessing thats because of [self.tableView reloadData];. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

restructure your code like this and i think it should work

```
// Loop Through XML Data
[rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {
[supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {
[loadingView setHidden:No];
...
...
...
...
...
...
[loadingView setHidden:YES];

}];
}];
```

Comment: Doing this does not display the loadingView